# Возможно ли использование файлов из input в стиль background-image?

Tags: javascript, css, css3, html5

Не могу догадаться как прочесть файлы через input.
Создан элемент:

```
<input multiple class="palFiles" type="file" accept="image/png" name="Pal0">
```

и из него я должен прочесть поступившие файлы.
За раз может быть загружено более 300 картинок.
Вопрос: можно ли использовать файлы, хранящиеся в input в стиль background-image?

```
var input = document.getElementsByClassName("palFiles")[0]
var current_character_image = document.getElementsByClassName("char")[0]
current_character_image.style.backgroundImage = a.files[25]
//этот вариант не сработал стиль background-image не изменяется
```

Элемент с классом `char` является блоком `<div>` в единственном экземпляре с выставленными параметрами высоты и ширины.

Вариант с использованием сервера или прописывание локальных путей типа `url(../img/<имяфайла>)`тут не прокатят.
Нужна локальная обработка файлов, где бы ни было приложение, на сервере или локально.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть такой класс как [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FileReader) (позволяет веб-приложениям асинхронно читать содержимое файлов (или буферы данных), хранящиеся на компьютере пользователя, используя объекты File или Blob, с помощью которых задается файл или данные для чтения.) и его метод [FileReader.readAsDataURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) - используется для чтения содержимого указанного Blob или File. По завершении, атрибут result будет содержать данные файла в виде data: URL

```js
function previewFile() {
  var preview = document.querySelector('img');
  var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
  var reader  = new FileReader();

  reader.onloadend = function () {
    preview.src = reader.result;
  }

  if (file) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  } else {
    preview.src = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="file" onchange="previewFile()"><br>
<img src="http://ctt.trains.com/sitefiles/images/no-preview-available.png" height="200" alt="Image preview...">
```

Comment: пока писал ответ, Вы уже ответили аналогично =)

Comment: благодарю, сработало.